# Why is Skype a `top` process after the application was closed?

Tags: launcher, skype, top, statusbar

If the Skype application has been exited via closing the window, why is it visible in `top` with usage sometimes at 2%?

Note also that it is absent from the `Status Bar` at the top of the screen. The Skype icon on the `Launcher` is showing no white dot as would be the case for open applications.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the window *doesn't* shutdown the program. It merely sends it to the background. The process is still there and your session is still open/alive.

Use the Menu **Skype** > **Exit** (or Quit) to actually close Skype.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can find a process and manually kill it, like
`kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep skype)`
or:
`pkill skype`